# Like dislike user

Tags: users

I'm working in a project for my clients and they want to add like/dislike buttons to the users profiles that for the users can rate each others. Have you guys worked on something similar? Can you tell me the guidelines to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

check the [Voting API](https://drupal.org/project/Votingapi) module. It is solid and does exactly what you want. From the module description:

> Rating of any content (comments, nodes, users, fish, whatever)
>   Multi-criteria voting (rate a game based on video, audio, and replayability)
>   Automatic tabulation of results (with support for different voting styles, like 'percentage' and '+1/-1').

You just may need to write few lines of code to reach your objective.